# Counting letters in an array. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Sorry if the wording/terminology is not accurate as possible, I'm relatively new to this coding stuff.

So I have a .txt file named somefile.txt
the contents of this file is as follows:

```
24 234 14
a8 267 35
35 378 28
b5 467 29
```

The file was loaded as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main (){
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("somefile.txt");
string contents;
while(!inputfile.eof())
    {
        getline(inputfile, contents);
        cout << contents;
    }
inputfile.close();
}
```

What I now want to do is to find out how many letters there are in this file and other files in the same format and of similar .txt files. For example, the somefile.txt has 2 letters that can be recognized by humans when they see the files contents. Is there a way for the computer to know/ calculate how many letters there are.
I was also hoping that this could be done in a separate function if possible.

Hopefully this clears up my poor writing from before.
Thank you again

Comment: What's an array of mixed data types?

Comment: I meant something with both letters and numbers in the same array.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt sure how else to say it

Comment: @ProNoobSry How do you actually declare that array in your code? If you have a `std::string` use `std::istringstream` to parse it further.

Comment: use `while(getline` not `while(!eof`

Comment: @M.M Thank you. If you don't mind explaining, is there a particular reason of using  while(getline(....)) instead of while(!...eof)  ?

Comment: yes, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @M.M I see, thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at ctype.h and use isletter or isalpha, etc. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/